# Rails model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model having comment id as primary key. Now I have another model note. I want to add note_id in user model. I have changed my associations

Previous associations:

```rb
# user.rb
belongs_to :comment
      
# comment.rb
has_many :users, -> { order('users.display_date DESC') },
dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :comment
```

Current associations:

```
# user.rb

belongs_to :note, optional: true

# note.rb

has_many :users, -> { order('users.display_date DESC') },
dependent: :destroy
```

I have added records in user model and inserting note_id. But fetching records in console showing nil value.

```
User.last.note
 => nil
```

Could someone help me where I am missing in associations?

Comment: Have you rename `comment_id` column to `note_id`?

Comment: The model is hard to understand, just to be sure... you are having multiple users per comment/note but users can only be part of [0..1] notes? Usually User has_many notes and notes belongs_to user. Or maybe its an N-to-N relation. This is just and observation I have no further knowledge of your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comment section,
something doesn't "feel right" in your association model.

You can "feel it" just by reading out loud `user belongs to comment` instead of `User has many Comments` or `Comment belongs to User`.

I am not sure if you are adding the notes model to your existing system or you switching from comments to notes, but please mind something doesn't seem okay!

### Let's fix the "User-Comment" relation problem first

```rb
# `users` table has no reference to comments
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

# `comments` table should have a `user_id` column
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

### Let's fix the "User-Note" relation problem

If you want just `one note per user`, I'd recommend:

```rb
# `users` table has no reference to notes
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :note
end

# `notes` table should have a `user_id` column
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Please let me know if it worked :)